SwiftData deleting model with Predicate
I'm seeing unusual behaviour in SwiftData when selectively deleting models using a predicate with try modelContext.delete(model: where:).  I have an easy workaround, but struggling to see why it works.
Two simple data structures.  My SwiftData model
@model Order {
   @Attribute(.unique) let orderID: String
   //...
}

and another struct
struct Drop {
   let id: String
   //...
}

I'm trying to delete an item from the context with (force unwrapping for brevity):
try! modelContext.delete(model: Order.self, where: #Predicate { order in order.orderID == drop.id})


which give the error in the Predicate macro of

Cannot convert value of type 'PredicateExpressions.Equal<PredicateExpressions.KeyPath<PredicateExpressions.Variable, String>, PredicateExpressions.KeyPath<PredicateExpressions.Value, String>>' to closure result type 'any StandardPredicateExpression'

Yet if I make the simple change to:
         let match = drop.id
         try! modelContext.delete(model: Order.self, where: #Predicate { order in order.orderID == match})

it compiles and works.  I'm unsure whether this is a gap in my understanding of predicates or, as it feels, just another SwiftData bug.

Right now the Predicate macro can't handle external values so your simple change is currently the way to do it.

Thanks @JoakimDanielson    So it's a gap in my understanding :-)  It's also a rather ugly smell.
